# Mean Value Theorem of Integrals for improper integrals:$\int_a^b f(x)g(x) \mathrm{d}x = f(a^+)\int_a^\xi g + f(b^-)\int_\xi^b g$

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals, means

This is the Mean Value Theorem of Integrals for improper integrals.

$\int_a^b g(x) \mathrm{d}x$ is convergent (a or b is a flaw, maybe they are all flaws). If f is monotonically bounded on $(a,b)$, then there is a $\xi \in (a,b)$ such that

$$\int_a^b f(x)g(x) \mathrm{d}x = f(a^+)\int_a^\xi g(x) \mathrm{d}x + f(b^-)\int_\xi^b g(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

By Mean Value Theorem of Integrals for proper integrals, there is infinite $\xi$ such that
$$\int_{a+\epsilon_1}^{b-\epsilon_2} f(x)g(x)\mathrm{d}x = f(a+\epsilon_1)\int_{a+\epsilon_1}^\xi g(x)\mathrm{d}x + f(b-\epsilon_2)\int_\xi^{b- \epsilon_2} g(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
for infinitely many $\epsilon_1 , \epsilon_2 >0$. So there is a limit point of $\xi$. But this limit point may be $a$ or $b$ so I don't know how to solve this quesiton.

Comment: You can approximate $g$ by a continuous function $h$ such that $\int_a^b f |g-h| < \epsilon$ when the improper integral converges absolutely and therefore $g$ is Lebesgue measurable and  integrable. Then this is easy to prove. If the integral is conditionally convergent it gets harder. I can probably figure it out or find a reference, but I generally ask if there is sufficient interest for me to pursue rather than write a long answer with no response.  It seems you have a sense of how to prove this by realizing that there is a sequence $\xi_n$ with a limit point.

Comment: Are you just concerned that $\xi_n$ converges to $a$ or $b$?

Comment: @RRL Exactly. (Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.